# Hide default view from getFolderContents results with TALES on Plone 4

Tags: plone

I am creating a secondary navigation bar on a Plone 4 site which looks at the contents of sub folders.

My site structure looks like the following:

```
Plone Site
|
|--Folder1
   |--PageA
   |--PageB
|--Folder2
   |--PageC
   |--PageD
```

My TALES is as follows (I appreciate that this is probably not the most elegant code):

```
<tal:subsections tal:define="isDocument python:getattr(context,'portal_type','') == 'Document';
                             isFolder python:getattr(context,'portal_type','') == 'Folder';
                             subitemsDocument python:context.aq_parent.aq_inner.getFolderContents(contentFilter={'portal_type':'Document'});
                             subitemsFolder python:context.getFolderContents(contentFilter={'portal_type':'Document'});
                             root_url context/portal_url;
                             front_url string:${root_url}/front-page;
                             current_url context/absolute_url;" tal:condition="context/portal_membership/isAnonymousUser">
  <ul id="subnav" tal:condition="isFolder">
    <tal:subtabsfolder tal:repeat="subitem subitemsFolder">
    <li tal:define="item_url subitem/getURL"
      tal:attributes="class python:current_url==item_url and 'selected' or 'plain'">
        <a tal:attributes="href subitem/getURL" tal:content="subitem/Title"/>
      </li>
    </tal:subtabsfolder>
  </ul>

  <ul id="subnav" tal:condition="isDocument">
    <tal:subtabsdocument tal:repeat="subitem subitemsDocument">
      <li tal:define="item_url subitem/getURL"
        tal:attributes="class python:current_url==item_url and 'selected' or 'plain'">
        <a tal:attributes="href subitem/getURL" tal:content="subitem/Title"
          tal:condition="python:front_url != current_url"/>
      </li>
    </tal:subtabsdocument>
  </ul>
</tal:subsections>
```

Everything is working well, my only problem is that I do not have a way of telling the template to ignore items that have been used as the default view of a container.

Is there a TALES condition I can use to accomplish this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use Plone's [context-utilities](http://developer.plone.org/misc/context.html) for that, like this:

`tal:condition="not: subitem/@@plone_context_state/is_default_page`

In case you're courious Six Feet Up provides a nice [quick-sheet](http://www.sixfeetup.com/technologies/plone-content-management/quick-reference-cards/utils-refcard.pdf), for more variable-references as a PDF.

By the way: I'd apply the condition to the list-element instead of the link element, to not render an unnecessary empty list-element.